# Changing an attribute value after copy

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Given the following XML example file :

```
<root>
    <list number="123">
        <element>
            <name value="Name1"/>
            <line value="Line 1 :"/>
        </element>
        <element>
            <name value="Name1"/>
            <line value="Line 1 :"/>
        </element>
    </list>
</root>
```

I want to create an XSL file allowing me to replace each occurrence of `Line 1 :` with `Line 1 : 123`, the `123` coming from the `list` node's attribute, `number`.

I have the following XSL file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="element">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="@value='Line 1 :'">
            <xsl:attribute name="type">
                <xsl:value-of select="root/list[@number]"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but the transformation fails and returns something like "Attributes and namespaces nodes cannot be added to the parent element after a text, comment, pi, or sub-element node has already been added".

Any idea about what is wrong with this XSL ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the error message you get:

> Attributes and namespaces nodes cannot be added to the parent element after a text, comment, pi, or sub-element node has already been added

explains the problem very well already. Your template matching `element` looks like this

```
<xsl:template match="element">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="@value='Line 1 :'">
        <xsl:attribute name="type">
```

The first instruction inside it:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
```

copies the `element` element with *all its content*. This includes child elements, text nodes, attributes and so on.

It is one of the rules of XSLT that once certain kinds of nodes are added to an element node, you cannot add more attribute nodes. But this is exactly what you are trying to do with

```
<xsl:attribute name="type">
```

which constructs an attribute node.

You do not actually need to `xsl:copy-of` the whole content of the `element` element, because you have an identity template in place that will copy everything anyway by default.

Only intervene in the exact spot that you would like to change. In this case, it is the `value` attribute of the `line` element - so write a template that matches exactly that.

---

I *think* what you need is the following. If not, please *show* the XML output you expect instead of describing it. I have assumed that there could be multiple `list` elements with varying `number` attributes.

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="element/line/@value">
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ', ../../../@number)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
   <list number="123">
      <element>
         <name value="Name1"/>
         <line value="Line 1 : 123"/>
      </element>
      <element>
         <name value="Name1"/>
         <line value="Line 1 : 123"/>
      </element>
   </list>
</root>
```

---

**EDIT**

> A more concise requirement would be : given any XML file, how can I concatenate any attribute value inside that is equal to "Line 1 :" with the 123 from the number above ? I assume that would need more than one template...

No, this would only be a small modification. Change the second template to:

```
<xsl:template match="list//@*[. = 'Line 1 :']">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ', ancestor::list[1]/@number)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I now see what was wrong... You assumed well concerning the desired output : multiple `list` elements with varying `number` attributes. In fact, to explain it easier, I want in the output everything from the input, but **anything** equals to "Line 1 :" must be concatenated with the `number` value. I tried with your XSLT, but it throws an error : "White space  cannot be stripped from input documents that have already been loaded."

Comment: @ThesaurusRex You are welcome. Do you mean that 1) a `@value` attribute with the value `Line 1 :` could occur on any element in the document or 2) the text `Line 1 :` can occur anywhere, in any element and as the value of any attribute? (To avoid these discussions for future questions, please make sure that your input document is _representative_ of your actual problems.)

Comment: @ThesaurusRex Re your edited comment: Are you using _exactly_ and _only_ my stylesheet? What XSLT processor / library do you use? As a quick fix delete this line `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` - it is not really important.

Comment: I was. And indeed, the problem comes from the `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` line, everything works fine when I remove it. I must admit that my question was not clear enough, I am sorry. I now have to work a bit more on my XSLT file. Thank you for your help !

Comment: @ThesaurusRex Can I ask you to accept my answer if it is sufficient for you? If not, please clarify your requirements (the questions in my first comment above) and I will modify my answer.

Comment: I would accept your answer if I had one more reputation post ;) Your answer gives me a nice path to work now. A more concise requirement would be : given any XML file, how can I concatenate **any** attribute value inside that is equal to "Line 1 :" with the `123` from the number above ? I assume that would need more than one template...

Comment: @ThesaurusRex Please see the edit to my answer - and let me know if this is what you need. You can experiment on this online [here](http://xsltransform.net/bFN1y9D). You should be able to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) regardless of your reputation.

Comment: It is exactly what I needed, thank you ! Accepting the answer, upvoting when I have 15 or more reputation !